# Splitting typical PHP variable in to different variables

Tags: php, split

My Php variable is

```
$rowdata = "58617 INDUSTRY ORIENTED MINI PROJECT 0 43 43 P";
```

if i print

```
$rowdata
```

then the output is

```
58617 INDUSTRY ORIENTED MINI PROJECT 0 43 43 P
```

and its html code is

```
58617
INDUSTRY ORIENTED MINI PROJECT
0
43
43
P
```

i need to split this variable in to

```
$split[0] = "58617";
$split[1] = "INDUSTRY ORIENTED MINI PROJECT";
$split[2] = "0";
$split[3] = "43";
$split[4] = "43";
$split[5] = "P";
```

I have tried with 
    $split = explode(" ", $rowdata);

but it is spliting in to 2 parts

can anyone please help me in doing this

Comment: Can the value of $split[1] contain numbers?

Comment: You need to give more sample data so we can create a formula to extract it... eg: will the first 5 characters always be numbers? Will the last 'P' always be a single character? etc

Comment: question edited , please look in

Comment: I see this data is here: http://share.pdfonline.com/d33ce7f418e74b469d516dabf5fec95a/bhargav.htm

What sets $rowdata? Maybe it would be easier to do this earlier on in your code?

Comment: how will system know how much data you require in `$split[1] = "INDUSTRY ORIENTED MINI PROJECT";`

Comment: @JmVerastigue yes some times it may contain numbers too along with characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very elegant - but it does the trick:

```
<?php
$rowdata = "58617 INDUSTRY ORIENTED MINI PROJECT 0 43 43 P";
$arr_dig = array_filter(preg_split('/\D/', $rowdata), 'strlen');
$arr_str = array_filter(preg_split('/\d/', $rowdata), 'strlen');
// remove unwanted spaces from the array
$arr_str = array_filter(array_map('trim', $arr_str));
//print_r($arr_dig);
//print_r($arr_str);
?>
```

Comment: this is working sir but array numbers are changing for different outputs , i am unable to insert it in database table

Comment: If the problem is the indexes - iterate the arrays using `foreach ($array as $value)` or surround it with a call to `array_values()`

Comment: Also, this will split when the "subject name" has a number in it.

Comment: its not wrking fr me sir, please can u edit ur answer with it, thankyou

Comment: @alfasin sir i have a negative number , How can i include negative number 58617 INDUSTRY ORIENTED MINI PROJECT 20 -1 20 F, like this, above code is ignoring -1 and printing it as 1, please help me sir

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$string = '58617 INDUSTRY ORIENTED MINI PROJECT 0 43 43 P';
$string = preg_replace('/([\d]+|[a-zA-Z\s]+) /', '$1-');
$parts = explode('-', $string);
```

The `preg_replace()` replaces every space that you need a break at with a dash, after that, the sting gets exploded at the dashes.

Comment: getting Warning: preg_replace() expects at least 3 parameters at $string = preg_replace('/(([0-9]+|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z])) /', '$1-'); line

Comment: change the second line to: `$string = preg_replace('/(([0-9]+|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z])) /', '$1-',$string);`

Comment: I think that you can improve the regex a bit by using `'/([\d]+|[a-zA-Z\s]+) /'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the the split variable from the data provided in the link it is much easier as it has proper delimiter.

Sample Code:

```
$rowdata = '<TR>
    <TD class="tr3 td20"><P class="p9 ft8">58617</P></TD>
    <TD class="tr3 td21"><P class="p8 ft8">INDUSTRY ORIENTED MINI PROJECT</P></TD>
    <TD class="tr3 td22"><P class="p13 ft8">0</P></TD>
    <TD class="tr3 td23"><P class="p14 ft8">47</P></TD>
    <TD class="tr3 td24"><P class="p12 ft8">47</P></TD>
    <TD class="tr3 td25"><P class="p8 ft8">P</P></TD>
    <TD class="tr3 td13"><P class="p6 ft5">&nbsp;</P></TD>
        </TR>';
if (preg_match_all('/<TD[^>]*><[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/P><\/TD>/i',$rowdata,$split_tmp) >0 ){
    $split=$split_tmp[1];
    print_r ($split[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

```
<?php
$rowdata = "58617 INDUSTRY ORIENTED MINI PROJECT 0 43 43 P";
//$rowdata = "58039 ADHOC & SENSORS NETWORKS 20 43 63 P";
$arr1=explode(" ",$rowdata);
$count=count($arr1);
$split[0]=$arr1[0];

for($i=1;$i<=($count-5);$i++){
    $split[1].=$arr1[$i] . " ";
}

$split[2]=$arr1[$count-4];
$split[3]=$arr1[$count-3];
$split[4]=$arr1[$count-2];
$split[5]=$arr1[$count-1];
print_r($split);
?>
```

Should also work for the other data.

Comment: This will work if it are always 6 parts. Which solution to pick depends on the actual data or use-case.

Comment: Array ( [0] => 58613 INDUSTRY [2] => 58613 INDUSTRY [3] => ORIENTED [4] => MINI [5] => PROJECT 0 44 44 P )

Comment: I based it on [this](http://share.pdfonline.com/d33ce7f418e74b469d516dabf5fec95a/bhargav.htm) user data. I think @user2501866 is copying directly from this data so the delimiters are different. From the way I look at it, it always has 6 parts. If you delete the whitespace and properly space the string, this solution should work.